# In VPS server if i start IIS7 then error is coming like this "cannot start service w3svc on computer '.'. what is the solution for this?

Tags: iis-7, iis

In VPS server if i start IIS7 then error is coming like this **cannot start service w3svc on computer '.'.**   what is the solution for this?

Comment: The solution to this is to fix whatever's preventing the `w3svc` from starting.  Which is about as detailed an explanation you'll get with the information you provided.

Answer (score 0):

> In VPS server

TOTALLY IRRELEVANT. Seriously. This is a Windows install of whatever sort, and whether this is physical or virtual hardware is as relevant than what you ate for breakfast.

> if i start IIS7 then error is coming like this cannot start service w3svc on computer '.'. what is 
>   the solution for this?

Get a professional admin looking at it ;)

Anyhow, get the error message. What you post here is NOT the error message by IIS, it is basically a generic error message by the service manager.

Consider - just in case you want to get this solved - to look into the event log and hunt for a real error message. A starting service can not provide any sensible information (the service manager API is not having a concept of this), and anyhow the windows accepted way to do that is to write one or more events into the event log. I am sure you will find some warnings or errors there.